# Updating multiple database records in a single query (using the conditional update query), with identical column values but different IDs

Tags: mysql

I have this one problem that I'm current facing right now. I want to update multiple records in a single SQL query. I include the visual of my table in this post as well.

This is my table

```
+----------+------------+------------+
| item_ID  | meta_name  | meta_value |
+----------+------------+------------+
| VwhDB0zs | item_price | 25.00      |
| tPmg309L | item_price | 25.00      |
+----------+------------+------------+
```

This is my current SQL statement:

```
UPDATE pt_item_meta
SET meta_value = CASE meta_name
   WHEN 'item_price' THEN '251.00' 
   WHEN 'item_price' THEN '325.20'
ELSE meta_value END
WHERE item_ID IN('tPmg3O9L','VwhDBOzS')
```

---

I want to update the records which have the same values (item_price) that are complement to their respective IDs.

But the problem is, this query will cause every record with meta_name = item_price to be updated to 251.00.

My goal is:

1. 251.00 should be the new item_price for item with ID tPmg309L
2. 325.20 should be the new item_price for item with ID VwhDB0zS

I didn't achieve my goal. So I came to a conclusion where this query isn't the solution for this specific situation.

Is there any better solution, anyone? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the case expression from the simple form to the searched form and add a condition for the `item_ID`:

```
UPDATE pt_item_meta
SET meta_value = 
 CASE 
   WHEN meta_name = 'item_price' AND item_ID = 'tPmg3O9L' THEN '251.00' 
   WHEN meta_name = 'item_price' AND item_ID = 'VwhDBOzS' THEN '325.20'
 END
WHERE item_ID IN('tPmg3O9L','VwhDBOzS')
```

Or you could rewrite it like this:

```
UPDATE pt_item_meta
SET meta_value = 
  CASE item_ID
   WHEN 'tPmg3O9L' THEN '251.00' 
   WHEN 'VwhDBOzS' THEN '325.20'
  END
WHERE item_ID IN ('tPmg3O9L','VwhDBOzS') 
  AND meta_name = 'item_price'
```

The important thing in both cases is that you check both conditions (item_ID and meta_name). Also, the `else` branch isn't needed as the predicates used to filter ensure that no other rows than the intended can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE pt_item_meta
SET meta_value = CASE 
   WHEN item_ID='tPmg3O9L'THEN '251.00' 
   WHEN item_ID= 'VwhDBOzS' THEN '325.20' END 
WHERE item_ID IN('tPmg3O9L','VwhDBOzS');
```

try this